# Glassfish 3.1.2 load native library (.dll)

Tags: java, dll, jar, glassfish, native

I am using a native library (OpenCV), for which I have the .jar and .dll. When I run a local Java project I simply add the .jar to the build path from Eclipse, and set the native library path. Then I load it with

```
System.load(absolutePath);
```

However, In the WebService I am trying to deploy on Glassfish I get a "Native library already loaded in another classloader" error. Which exactly is the proper procedure to include the .jar and .dll in a Glassfish project?